# Get current sort options when sort changes in vuetify data tables

Tags: vuetify.js

Our tables pagination and sorting are all done on the server, but I still want to allow the user to click column headers to sort. I need to access the tables sort options when the sorting changes. It seems the events are split

```
update:sort-by
update:sort-desc
```

I *could* create two methods, have the first event set the column (sort-by) value, and then the second method actually trigger the sort. But that sounds horrible and prone to race conditions or future bugs.

It would be better if the sort-by included the desc/asc data as well. I tried creating a ref to the table, but for some reason the properties containing the sort information are empty.

The event update:options contains all the necessary information, but that could fire for reasons other than sorting which isn't ideal either.

So I'm not sure if I'm missing something here. Is there a better way to accomplish this?

```
                                <v-data-table
ref="contractItemTable"
:headers="headers"
:items="contracts"
:disable-sort="isLoadingPage"
:server-items-length="tableTotal"
disable-pagination
hide-default-footer
@click:row="navigateToContract"
single-select
@update:sort-by="sortTable"
@update:sort-desc="sortTable"
item-key="id.id">
```

And the JS

```
public sortTable(event) {

    console.debug(this.$refs.contractItemTable.sortBy);
    console.debug(this.$refs.contractItemTable.sortDesc);
}
```

No matter what I click, the sortBy and sortDesc properties are empty. If I use the options event, the event contains the correct sortBy and sortDesc. But as stated above, not exactly the event I want to use. I have it working, but I have to "ignore" the initial load options event since it's not a valid time for this method to fire.

Comment: Can you post your code?

Comment: Updated with code. Not sure it'll be much good though. Seems the ref to the table doesn't ever get updated with the sort data. It contains the actual data and other stuff. But not the sort. So I think this might be a bug with the library.

Answer (score 2):

You're mostly there (and found your question while trying to sort out the best way to apply sorting to derived/computed column-items myself) ... just need to bind the v-data-table sort-by and sort-desc attributes to data elements so that you can refer to them in your sortTable function:

```
<v-data-table
    ...
    :items="contracts"
    :headers="headers"
    :sort-by.sync="sortBy"
    :sort-desc.sync="sortDesc"
    @update:sort-by="sortTable"
    @update:sort-desc="sortTable"
    ...
>

export default {
    data() {
        contracts: [],
        sortBy: 'contractDate',  // make sure this matches headers[].value
        sortDesc: false, // and both match your initial from-server sort
        ...
        headers: [
            { text: 'Contract Date', sortable: true, value: 'contractDate' },
            { text: 'Contract Value', sortable: true, value: 'contractValue' }
            ...
        ]


    },
    methods: {
        sortTable() {
            if(this.sortBy === 'contractDate') {
                this.contracts.sort( (a,b) => {
                    return ( a.contractDate > b.contractDate ? 1 : -1 ) * (this.sortDesc ? -1 : 1 );
                });
            }
            if(this.sortBy === 'contractValue') {
                this.contracts.sort( (a,b) => {
                    return ( a.contractValue > b.contractValue ? 1 : -1 ) * (this.sortDesc ? -1 : 1 );
                });
            }
            
        }
    }
}
```

Your sort logic obviously will vary, but included the Array.sort() callback example there to show where this.sortDesc is used to reverse the evaluation.

A big caveat to be aware of is that if you do not specify

```
<v-data-table :must-sort="true" >
```

Then the bound @update:sort-by and @update:sort-desc events will BOTH fire when sort is deactivated which happens when user clicks the same column header a third time (it cycles through sorted to no-sort states.)

To get around this, add something like

```
sortPending: false
```

to your data state, and when the event fires, return immediately out of the event if this.sortPending === true, and move your sort logic into a Vue.nextTick() callback:

```
    methods: {
        sortTable() {
            if(this.sortPending) return;
            this.sortPending = true;
            this.$nextTick( () => {
                this.sortPending = false;
                /* your sort logic here */
            });
```

Answer (score 1):

In data table add attribute:

```
:sort-desc.sync="sort_desc"
```

In data:

```
sort_desc:true,//or what you need by default
```

In observable:

```
sort_desc:function(val,_prev){
    //do what you need to change sort and refresh
},
```